# Web Services integration with opencms

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, opencms

I am new to OpenCms and I am doing some POC on it.I have googled a lot but I didn't find anything regarding web services integration with opencms. I want to know how we 
can integrate Web services with openCms.

Answer (score 1):

i found these two useful examples:

- [Tihomir's solution](http://tihomirmateev.blogspot.it/2010/04/deploying-custom-web-services-in.html) (Web Service with Axis and OpenCMS)
- [Simone's solution](http://simone-folino.blogspot.it/2012/04/expose-web-service-from-opencms-with.html) (Web Service with Apache CXF and OpenCMS)

In short both solutions rely on creation of custom OpenCMS module to define the service ([here](http://arquivo.bng-galiza.org/opencms/opencms/alkacon-documentation/documentation_modules/create_modules.html) How to create a new OpenCms module) and editing web.xml to register the servlet